# Проблема с cетевыми потоками в ubuntu, *lock == ((ath_mutex_t) 0)'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сокет, сеть

```
GENERAL: Parallel Hosts: 2 Parallel Logins: 10
GENERAL: Total Hosts: 2785 
GENERAL: Total Users: 12
GENERAL: Total Passwords: 52
medusa: ath.c:193: _gcry_ath_mutex_lock: Assertion `*lock == ((ath_mutex_t) 0)' failed.
medusa: ath.c:193: _gcry_ath_mutex_lock: Assertion `*lock == ((ath_mutex_t) 0)' failed.
```

Comment: есть идеи ? есть у кого опыт работы с медузой ?

Comment: Как насчёт внятной формулировки проблемы? Что не так работает?